# How to get parameter in postman

Tags: javascript, php, backend

How to get the parameter of sensor and dateandtime, also it based on the latest dateandtime and limit into 1 when the sensor is just the same.

```
[
    {
        "0": "2017-10-19 08:36:45",
        "dateandtime": "2017-10-19 08:36:45",
        "1": "SewingSection",
        "sensor": "SewingSection",
        "2": "25.6",
        "temperature": "25.6",
        "3": "54",
        "humidity": "54",
        "4": "1",
        "id": "1"
    },
    {
        "0": "2017-10-19 08:38:01",
        "dateandtime": "2017-10-19 08:38:01",
        "1": "SewingSection",
        "sensor": "SewingSection",
        "2": "25.6",
        "temperature": "25.6",
        "3": "53.9",
        "humidity": "53.9",
        "4": "2",
        "id": "2"
    },
    {
        "0": "2017-10-19 08:40:02",
        "dateandtime": "2017-10-19 08:40:02",
        "1": "SewingSection",
        "sensor": "SewingSection",
        "2": "25.6",
        "temperature": "25.6",
        "3": "53.7",
        "humidity": "53.7",
        "4": "3",
        "id": "3"
    }
]
```

I already tried in postman `http://localhost:8888/getData.php?length=1&sensor=SewingSection&dateandtime=2017-10-19 08:40:02`.
but still it doesn't work.

expected output

```
{
            "0": "2017-10-19 08:40:02",
            "dateandtime": "2017-10-19 08:40:02",
            "1": "SewingSection",
            "sensor": "SewingSection",
            "2": "25.6",
            "temperature": "25.6",
            "3": "53.7",
            "humidity": "53.7",
            "4": "3",
            "id": "3"
        }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: `I already tried` - we can't see your server, so while that looks like it could do what you want, without knowing a thing about the server code, the answer is a pineapple

Comment: Is that array the response you already get or is it what you're expecting to get?

Comment: We need a better explanation of what's going on here. Your title has "Postman" in the title, and a JSON payload, but you said you tried a URL? Are you sending a POST request with Postman? or a GET request with query string parameters? Are you asking about environment variables in the Postman client? or referencing some values passed in PHP? If this is related to PHP, can you provide some PHP code of what you've tried? Please [edit] to answer some of these questions.

Comment: @digijay I already update my question

Comment: And as HPierce already asked, what's in `getData.php`?